# How to focus a react-router Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an input box used for searching, and want to be able to press the down key to move focus from the input to the first of a list of `<Link>`s.  It seems what I have here won't work, since `<Link>` isn't an actual DOM node.  I am able to get it to work using `<a>` instead of `<Link>` though.

```
let Link = require('react-router').Link

let SearchAndSelect = React.createClass({
  handleKeyPress: function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 40) { //'down' key
      this.refs['searchBox'].blur()
      this.refs['link0'].focus()
    }
  },

  render: function () {
    let ids = ['1', '2' , '3']

    return (
      <div>
        <input onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress} ref="searchBox"/>

        <div>
          {ids.map((id, key) => (
            <Link to={`thing/${id}`}
              ref={`link${key}`}>
              {id}
            </Link>        
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Is there a way to use `focus()` with a react-router `<Link>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['link0']).focus()` it should work.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  I better understand *findDOMNode* now.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a real direct way to do this but one thing you can do is:

```
<div ref={`link${key}`}>
  <Link to={`thing/${id}`}
    {id}
  </Link>    
</div>
```

wrap your link in a div and then put the ref on the div itself. Link returns an `<a>` tag with props attached.

```
 if (e.keyCode === 40) { //'down' key
    this.refs['searchBox'].blur()
    this.refs['link0'].children[0].focus()
  }
```

when you access the div ref you can just use `.children[0]` which will grab the a tag. This is a hacky approach and relies on react router Link always just rendering an a tag, but it will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To add a ref to the `<a>` rather than the `Link` component, you can use the React Router `innerRef` prop.

Something like 
`` <Link to={`thing/${id}`} innerRef={`link${key}`} >... ``

The docs are here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/innerref-function

Comment: This should get more up votes! I was using styled-components `styled(Link)` and needed a reference to the link so I could programmatically focus here. The `ref` I created was undefined. I went to using a `styled.a` instead and that worked for the web, but failed on the iPhone. iOS does not support/has problems with `<a></a>` tags and the links didn't work on the phone. Reading the link to the documents help to solved my problem: instead of `ref` I use `innerRef` and it works.